# Forwarding e-mail

Tags: halacha, internet, mail

Is there a halacha or other rabbinical consensus concerning a sole recipient of an e-mail forwarding the message to another person? I ask this question in the context of business. I recently received an e-mail from a supervisor who gave directions that involved other people. Would there be any ethical, moral or legal violation if I were to send the other parties a copy of the e-mail?

Answer (score 4):

> one is to assume that anything one is told is to be kept secret unless
>   specifically instructed otherwise

from http://www.torahmusings.com/2013/02/keeping-secrets/, by Rabbi Ari Enkin, citing Yoma 4b

Comment: That may be true...but what about the specific case mentioned in the question, where one was given instructions that concerned other people as well (I assume there is no other private content in that particular message)?